# Converting Date field to Date Time while importing excel file

Tags: python, excel, datetime

```
import pathlib
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd
import sys
import csv
import numpy as np
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
import os
import datetime as dt 
from datetime import datetime

xlsx_file = (r'//test/MCC.xlsx')
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(xlsx_file)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
plu = []
for row in range(num_rows):
    plu.append([sheet.cell(row,col).value for col in range(sheet.ncols)])

for item in plu:

call_date = dt.datetime.strptime(str(int(item[1])),'%f')
new_call_date = call_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
item[1] = new_call_date
```

call_date is the 2nd column(item[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMu86.png)) in each row. The excel sheet contains these dates in a m/d/Y format. upon Importing it's transformed to some sort of time stamp?? (i.e  43948)

Im attempting to use strptime and then strftime but upon using the strftime all dates are converted from time stamp to 1/1/1900.

[data before importing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMu86.png)
[data after converting with above snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCfh3.png)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Adding images of data column I'm referencing

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer because we are totally blind. Could you please show at least a part of your data?

However, as a first part of answer, if you import your data as a DataFrame with e.g. (and the correct options settings specific to your dataset):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel(r'//test/MCC.xlsx')
```

then you could use e.g.:

```
pd.to_datetime(data.your_column, format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

Comment: Added some screenshots of the data column I'm referencing. Going to try importing as DF as well. Thank you

Comment: Based on your screenshots this solution should help you!

Comment: Worked perfectly, after I used the line you included to convert series to datetime. I used a simple strftime for formatting and got expected output m/d/Y format. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in method (which is very slow):

```
pd.read_excel('my_data.xlsx', parse_dates=True)
```